# How to references other generic parameters for ComponentOptions in module augmentation?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Here is what I want to do in my `.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'vue/types/options' {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    beforeInstance?: (options: ComponentOptions<V>) => void | Promise<(vm: CombinedVueInstance<V, Data, Methods, Computed, Props>) => any | undefined>;
  }
}
```

It did not work due to it don't know about `Data`, `Methods`, `Computed` and `Props`. I already tried putting those variables into `ComponentOptions` like this:

```
declare module 'vue/types/options' {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue, Data=DefaultData<V>, Methods=DefaultMethods<V>, Computed=DefaultComputed, PropsDef=PropsDefinition<DefaultProps>, Props=DefaultProps> {
    beforeInstance?: (options: ComponentOptions<V>) => void | Promise<(vm: CombinedVueInstance<V, Data, Methods, Computed, Props>) => any | undefined>;
  }
}
```

It will break type inference in my component definition:

```
export default Vue.extend({
  data: function () {
    return {
      value: 'abc'
    };
  },
  mounted: function () {
    console.log(this.value); // This does not work.
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @PhilippKühn yes, but I can't remember how I solved it.